# array_chunk in email body php

Tags: php

I have a form where user can click on a button to add as many partecipants as he needs. For every partecipant I have 4 fields. Those fields are automatically added with a script when I click on the button to add partecipants. The fields are created as [data] so I have this in my php file to send the email:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
$postdata = $_REQUEST['data'];
}

if( isset($postdata) ) {
    $altri = implode('<hr>', array_chunk($postdata, 4, true));

}
else {
    $altri = 'Non sono stati aggiunti altri partecipati a questa richiesta';
}
```

then in my $body I try to print the result as:

```
$body = <<<EOD
<strong>Altri partecipanti:</strong><br>$altri<br>

// PHP email sender
mail($to, $sub, $body, $headers);
```

As you can see I try to group and separate those 4 fields in the email output to obtain something like:

- field_1_participant_1
- field_2_participant_1
- field_3_participant_1
- field_4_participant_1

separator

- field_1_participant_2
- field_2_participant_2
- field_3_participant_2
- field_4_participant_2

...
etc...

I'm not able to let it work as intended and I got an error message for "Array to string conversion"

How could I write the code to obtain it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about what `array_chunk` does. It produces an array of **arrays**, eg `[ ['f1p1', 'f2p1', 'f3p1', 'f4p1'], ['f1p2', 'f2p2', 'f3p2', 'f4p2'] ]`

Comment: Thanks Phil for suggestion; I've tryed to implode again $altri = implode("\n <br>", $altri); but no way... I don't really know what to do; any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what `array_chunk` does. It produces an array of arrays, eg

```
[ ['f1p1', 'f2p1', 'f3p1', 'f4p1'], ['f1p2', 'f2p2', 'f3p2', 'f4p2'] ]
```

Try using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-map.php) to convert the inner arrays into strings. For example

```
$altri = implode('<hr>', array_map(function($list) {
    return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $list) . '</li></ul>';
}, array_chunk($postdata, 4)));
```

---

This produces

```
<ul><li>f1p1</li><li>f2p1</li><li>f3p1</li><li>f4p1</li></ul><hr><ul><li>f1p2</li><li>f2p2</li><li>f3p2</li><li>f4p2</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `implode` each chunk separately and then `implode` imploded chunks:

```
if( isset($postdata) ) {
    $altri = [];
    $chunks = array_chunk($postdata, 4, true);
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        $altri[] = implode('<br />', $chunk);
    }

    $altri = implode('<hr>', $altri);
}
```